# How do I call pathauto alias using php

Tags: path-aliases

I have pathauto installed on my D7 setup along with all my taxonomy terms configured.

How do I then call the alias using PHP for custom code?

EDIT: just to clear things up - I want to output the alias URL that has been created and assigned to each specific node. For example:

Terms
- Country
- City

For node #1 an alias is created as {site}/[country]/[city]

I would like to output the alias that has been created for the node so I can visit for example {site]/england/london instead of {site}/node/1

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the alias for the taxonomy term you can use [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) (if you just want the URL), or [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) if you want a link:

```
$url = url('taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid);

$link = l('Link text', 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid);
```

Both of those will give you the current path alias for the term page

Comment: also `$path = drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid);` if all you want is the bare path.